# Detectar dependencias instaladas en LINUX mediante comandos - SCRIPTING BASH

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

Estoy haciendo un script en bash en el que voy a instalar unas dependencias de forma automática y para ello quiero saber si la dependencia que voy a instalar está instalada o no.
He utilizado el comando "test -f " pero no funciona con todas las dependencias.

```
test -f dependencia
```

También he probado mediante "which dependencia" pero tampoco funciona con todas las dependencias.

```
which /ruta/dependencia
```

También he probado mediante "apt -qq list dependencia 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4" para obtener como respuesta "[instalado]" si está instalada o un "" si no está instalada la dependencia.

```
apt -qq list dependencia 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

No encuentro la mejor forma de verificar si las dependencias están instaladas o no, si alguien sabe la mejor forma de hacerlo y me echa una mano se lo agradecería.

Comment: podes usar `apt list --installed | grep php8.0-zip` o `dpkg-query -l | grep php8.0-zip`

Comment: Al final he utilizado todas las opciones como test, which y apt y he metido en una condicional los posibles resultado positivos. No se si será la mejor forma pero creo que puede ser la más completa. He probado de la manera que dices pero con dpkg-query -l | grep dependencia me devuelve un resultado muy generico que no me sirve pero gracias por contestar !